# dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier doesn't go through init nor initWithCoder functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

When creating cells for `UICollectionView`, `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` doesn't go through `init` nor `initWithCoder` function of `CategoryView`.

The view is creating, it has a proper type (`CategoryView`) but `init` nor `initWithCoder` of `CategoryView` is not called, so essential functionality is not executed. Is there some other init in this senario?

```
- (CategoryView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CategoryView *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CategoryView" forIndexPath:indexPath];    
    [cell someConfiguration];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `initWithCoder` is not called either

Comment: as this method is dequeuing the already used cell -init method of that cell will get called only one time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the problem was that the base class was not specified for your cell prototype in Interface Builder. So make sure the base class is set:

[image]

Then, when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`, using the storyboard identifier you specified in the prototype cell, it calls `initWithCoder` when the cell is first instantiated. If the cell scrolls out of view and is later re-used for another `NSIndexPath`, the [`prepareForReuse`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse) is called:

```
@interface CategoryView : UICollectionViewCell

@end

@implementation CategoryView

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"init");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    NSLog(@"reuse");
}

@end
```

Comment: It doesn't called at all

Comment: Bless you :) Put it as an answer. I'll check it

Answer (score 2):

try `- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`

It works for me. I wrote UI programmatically.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionViews and UITableViews reuse cells to improve performance. initWithCoder: will only run once *per reusable cell*. As such, if you need something called every time a cell is *displayed* I would recommend writing a method as follows in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
- (CategoryView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CategoryView *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CategoryView" forIndexPath:indexPath]; 

    // self.parameters = an NSDictionary of the colors, text, etc. you need to the cell to know about
    [cell configureWithParameters:self.parameters];

    return cell;
}
```

Then, inside your configureWithParameters: method you can include colors, text, etc. that will help you setup your CategoryView.

You'll have to declare your configureWithParameters: method in your CateogryView.h as follows:

```
// CategoryView.h
- (void)configureCell:(NSDictionary *)parameters;
```

Then include your customizations in the .m as follows:

```
// CategoryView.m
- (void)configureCell:(NSDictionary *)parameters{
    // Put Whatever initialization code you need here
    // Example:
    self.label.textColor = parameters["color"];
    self.label.text = parameters["text"];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't called at all

Comment: 1. I have it. 2.init should have been called before any configuration

Comment: And init: won't be called again. What configuration are you trying to do that can't be called using a publicly exposed method?

Comment: I think that is the best way to custom your class. My init class doesn't fired as well, and using this solution is better. But still wondering, why any init method doesn't fired at all.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you have collection view delegate/datasource connected to your class.
- Make sure you give base class for cell.
- Make sure your cell has reuse identifier.
- Make sure to register Nib for your reuse identifier. (You don't need to do that if your cell present in your collection view in storyboard).

And finally try changing

```
- (CategoryView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

to

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Now your

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
```

Should be called.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've subclassed UICollectionViewCell, you can put your initialization code in awakeFromNib().